# Making a Pig Game using Object Oriented Programming (Java)

Tags: java

Hey guys so I made a Pig Game in Java for my CS project. I didn't have too much trouble with it because I only used one class. However, my professor now is making us implement OOP, and I'm having a lot of trouble. Here is my working Pig Game:

```
package edu.bsu.cs121.zmbarnes;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PigGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int player1TurnScore = 0;
    int player1TotalScore = 0;
    int player2TurnScore = 0;
    int player2TotalScore = 0;
    int dice;
    int dice2;
    String input = "r";
    char repeat;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random diceRoll = new Random();

    System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Pig!\n");

    while(player1TotalScore < 100 || player2TotalScore < 100){
        // human's turn
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("It is Player 1's turn.");
        do{
            dice = diceRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("You rolled a " + dice);

            if(dice == 1){
                player1TurnScore = 0;
                System.out.println("You lose your turn!");
                System.out.println("Your total score is " + player1TotalScore);
                break;
            }else{
                player1TurnScore += dice;
                System.out.println("Your turn score is " + player1TurnScore);
                System.out.println("And your total score is " + player1TotalScore);
                System.out.println("If you hold, " + player1TurnScore + " points will be added to your total score.");
                System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll again, or 'h' to hold.");
                input = keyboard.nextLine();
                repeat = input.charAt(0);

                if(repeat == 'h'){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || dice != 1);

        player1TotalScore += player1TurnScore;
        System.out.println("Your score is " + player1TotalScore);
        player1TurnScore = 0;

        if(player1TotalScore >= 100){
            System.out.println("Your total score is " + player1TotalScore);
            System.out.println("PLAYER 1 WINS!");
            break;
        }

        // Player 2's turn
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("It is Player 2's turn.");
        do{
            dice2 = diceRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
            System.out.println("You rolled a " + dice2);

            if(dice2 == 1){
                player2TurnScore = 0;
                System.out.println("You lose your turn!");
                System.out.println("Your total score is " + player2TotalScore);
                break;
            }else{
                player2TurnScore += dice2;
                System.out.println("Your turn score is " + player2TurnScore);
                System.out.println("And your total score is " + player2TotalScore);
                System.out.println("If you hold, " + player2TurnScore + " points will be added to your total score.");
                System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll again, or 'h' to hold.");
                input = keyboard.nextLine();
                repeat = input.charAt(0);

                if(repeat == 'h'){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }while(input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || dice2 != 1);

        player2TotalScore += player2TurnScore;
        System.out.println("Your score is " + player2TotalScore);
        player2TurnScore = 0;

        if(player2TotalScore >= 100){
            System.out.println("Your total score is " + player2TotalScore);
            System.out.println("PLAYER 2 WINS!");
            break;
        }
    }
    keyboard.close();
}
}
```

I must use a Dice class with a roll() method, a Player class with void takeTurn(), void bankPoints(), void makeChoice(), and boolean hasWon() methods, a GameOfPig class with , and Project class with void play() method, and the main Project class with main().

I'm just having trouble conceptualization how I can move my code into those methods so the game will work the exact same way. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to OOD. My brief answer is highly borrowed from your code. I hope other one could correct me. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
public class PigGame {
    Dice dice;
    Player player1;
    Player player2;

    public PigGame() {
        this.player1 = new Player("Player1");
        this.player2 = new Player("Player2");
        this.dice = new Dice();
    }

    public void play() {


        while (!player1.hasWon() && !player2.hasWon()) {
            player1.takeTurn(dice);
            if (!player1.hasWon())
                player2.takeTurn(dice);
        }

        if (player1.hasWon()) {
            System.out.println("Player1 won!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Player2 won!");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PigGame pg = new PigGame();
        pg.play();
    }
}

class Dice {
    private static Random diceRoll = new Random();

    public int roll() {
        return diceRoll.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }
}

class Player {
    private int currentRoundScore = 0;;
    private int totalScore = 0;
    private String playerName;

    public Player(String name) {
        this.playerName = name;
    }

    public void takeTurn(Dice dice) {
        currentRoundScore = 0;
        System.out.println("-------It's " + playerName + "'s turn.--------");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "r";
        int diceValue = 0;

        do {
            diceValue = dice.roll();
            System.out.println("You rolled a " + diceValue);

            if(diceValue == 1){
                currentRoundScore = 0;
                System.out.println("You lose your turn!");
                System.out.println("Your total score is " + totalScore);
                break;
            }else{
                currentRoundScore += diceValue;
                System.out.println("Your turn score is " + currentRoundScore);
                System.out.println("If you hold, " + currentRoundScore + " points will be added to your total score. And your total score would be " + currentRoundScore + totalScore);
                System.out.println("Enter 'r' to roll again, or 'h' to hold.");
                input = keyboard.nextLine();
                char repeat = input.charAt(0);

                if(repeat == 'h'){
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("r") || diceValue != 1);

        bankPoints();
    }

    public boolean hasWon() {
        return totalScore >= 100;
    }

    public void bankPoints() {
        totalScore += currentRoundScore;
        System.out.println(playerName + "'s total score is " + totalScore + "\n");
    }
}
```